# Any other type of numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question

So I've heard that all finite abelian groups are isomorphic to direct sums of the integers or of integers modulo a power of a prime, then you get that all extensions of reals are basically the real numbers or the p-adic number.

Is there any such theorem for the rationals? Any other way of creating numbers that is not some vector space or an algebra over the reals? The way the complex numbers are just two dimensional real numbers and the grassman algebra is just an algebra of the complex numbers. I gues what I am saying is, is there any other way to do multiplication that is really new? Not having a copy of the natural numbers embedded inside?

Comment: "all extensions of reals are basically the real numbers or the p-adic number"? "grassman algebra is just an algebra of the complex numbers"? And what does the finite abelian groups thing have to do with algebras? ... At any rate, rings of positive characteristic are not extensions of the naturals, though (unital) rings are in some sense extensions of a quotient of the integers. Rings may not be algebras over fields, and may not even be free as modules over the subring generated by $1$ (e.g. $\Bbb Z_4[2x]$ is not free over $\Bbb Z_4$).

Comment: Ok. Let me be more concrete then. Are there any other fields than the rationals that include the integers but do not contain the rationals?

Comment: No. If a field includes the integers then it includes the rationals, since fields are closed under nonzero division.

Comment: Ok, so is there any way to construct a field that does not include the naturals in any way?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "in any way." A field contains a multiplicative identity called $1$, which generates a subfield called the *prime subfield*. The prime subfield will be either $\Bbb Q$ in characteristic $0$ or $\Bbb F_p$ (aka $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$) in characteristic $p$. The finite field $\Bbb F_p$ of course cannot contain the integers $\Bbb Z$ as a subring (or the naturals $\Bbb N$ as a semiring), but $\Bbb F_p$ is a quotient (aka homomorphic image) of $\Bbb Z$ (not $\Bbb Q$), so the elements of $\Bbb F_p$ are typically represented as integers. You should verify everything I'm saying.

Comment: I see. Ok, but if you make multiplication satisfy other property than associativity or commutativity, similar to Lie algebra that satisfy the Jacobi indentity and is anticommutative  I don't count Lie algebras as they can have scalar multiples which means that the naturals still are there somehow, That is to say algebras over a field are not allowed but if you had an abelian group with non-associative multiplication, would that work, would you have to make addition no longer abelian to get rid of naturals or a quotient of them?

Comment: You say you don't count Lie algebras as they have scalar multiples. This applies in any abelian group: for any $g\in G$ and $n\in\Bbb Z$ we can define $ng$. Having another operation called multiplication is not relevant to that. Even if $G$ is not abelian, we no longer write the operation additively and generally write it multiplicatively, so the notation would then be $g^n$, but it's the same thing and still involves integers. Even if there's no associativity or inverses (a magma), the expression $g^n$ for naturals $n$ can still make sense unless you go so far you remove power-associativity.

Comment: Ok so could you make a structure with 2 binary operations both of them not power-associative? and with inverses? and distributivity of one operation over the other?